# Extend WCF declaration to add parameter entry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, service

I was wondering if there was an easy way to add parameters to a service connection? Essentially I want to do something as simple as passing a integer through a service connection where all available methods have the ability to access this parameter.

Here's a diagram of the design:

[image]

Essentially application servers will get an id that can be passed when communicating with a WCF services for many reasons. Is there an easy way to integrate this functionality into a wcf service to be used by methods at runtime?

The functionality I'm looking for is something like:

Service1Client myService = new Service1Client();

myService.customValue = 1234;

That will be passed globally to all methods within that service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a static member in the service(s).

If you want different clients to have different ids in the service,
you'll have to have the clients pass a session id to all service operation contracts,
you can use session id, together with static dictionary to access internal id.
Use a longer session id then internal id to prevent spoofing (long or guid).